# Display list items centered with dynamic height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

So I am trying to make list items equal size and align inside content in the middle. All I get is a big mess. Also, another important thing I want the `a` tag link to work on the whole list element - so on the whole square. Right not the link only works if you press is on the `a` tag only. Is it possible to do it, without changing the HTML structure?

**So the main things:**

1. The height of the `<li>` item can vary, because of the contents inside, but not the width and I am trying to make all of them the same height.
2. Make the whole `<li>` area clickable, so it would redirect to the `<a>` tag reference page. Without changing the current structure.
3. Center the content in `<li>` tag and don't overflow the container.
4. In the example, the content inside the last `<li>` element, the text, and the `<a>` tag is in the same line. How could I properly make them in different lines?

In the example below, it is the typical structure I need to style.

```css
.ul {
  display: flex;
}

.test1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #9affda;
  color: black;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="test1"><a href="">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</a></li>
  <li class="test1"><a href="">TEST TEST TEST</a></li>
  <li class="test1"><a href="">TEST TEST TEST</a></li>
  <li class="test1">Test text </li>
  <li class="test1">Test text <a href="">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried multiple approaches but every time something would go wrong [*look at the main things I am trying to do*]. I tried display `table` and `table-cell`, `flex` and `inline-flex`, `inline-block` and all other kinds of things...

## Goal output

[image: Goal output]

The blue squares are `<li>` elements. The `<a>` tag is called `link inside` and regular text is `text inside`.

Comment: So, what is your expectation, can you create an image that show the final result you want to achieve?

Comment: I added an image of wanted output. Hope it is more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were most of the way there and we can achive most (but not all) of your requirements just by using `flex-direction:column`.

> 1. The height of the `<li>` item can vary, because of the contents inside, but not the width and I am trying to make all of them the same height.
> 2. Make the whole `<li>` area clickable, so it would redirect to the `<a>` tag reference page. *Without changing the current structure.*

**NB** - No.2:  This is not possible with CSS *unless* the link is 100% width/height of the `li`. In this case there is a separate text node which means that the link is a not (and cannot be) that size. You would need Javascript.

> 3. Center the content in `<li>` tag and don't overflow the container.
> 4. In the example, the content inside the last `<li>` element, the text, and the `<a>` tag is in the same line. How could I properly make them in different lines?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.test1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #9affda;
  color: black;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background: darkseagreen;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="test1"><a href="">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</a></li>
  <li class="test1"><a href="">TEST TEST TEST</a></li>
  <li class="test1"><a href="">TEST TEST TEST</a></li>
  <li class="test1">Test text </li>
  <li class="test1">Test text <a href="">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was afraid that  #2 it won't be really possible. But you know the clients! They want what they want. Thank you for your help. The `flex-direction: column;` instead of `display: inline-flex;` is a new approach I haven't tried yet and it sees to work better in this case!

Answer (score 1):

okay,
the first thing is that in your css, you write ".ul" but you have not any class "class="ul""!

if you write in your css only "ul{}" it change everything.

then, if you want that your entire square will be a link, you need to change the order that you write your list!

it's :

```
<ul>
    <a href="">
        <li> TEST </li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

and your css:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I specified in the post : it needs to be done without changing the structure. It is dynamically made in the back-end and I can not edit the structure of it. So I was more looking into stretch and other CSS options.

Comment: @Wanilla: You say that you cannot change "the structure of the HTML" because it is getting generated. What can you change? CSS? JavaScript?

Comment: I can change only the CSS, sadly.